# Executing raw SQL on the SQLAlchemy engine versus a session

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

What is the difference between executing raw SQL on the SQLAlchemy **engine** and the **session**? Specifically against a **MSSQL** database.

> engine.execute('DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE MyId IN(1, 2, 3)')

versus

> session.execute('DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE MyId IN(1, 2, 3)')

I've noticed that executing the SQL on the session, cause MSSQL to '**hang**'.

Perhaps someone has an idea on how these two executions are different, or perhaps someone can point me where to further investigate.

Comment: You can set `echo=True` on your `create_engine` call and every query will be printed out. Check what are the differences between the two.

Comment: `engine.execute(..)` might create a new transaction, whereas `session.execute(..)` uses the current transaction of the session. I guess the difference might be related to that. Try to enable `SQL` logging as per @Dekel's comment to understand why? or perform `session.commit()` or `session.rollback()` just before `session.execute` to test this hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why MSSQL Server was hanging, was not because of the difference between calling execute on the engine or the session, but because a delete was being called on the table, without a commit, and then a subsequent read.